# Sublime Text 3 sidebar not changing with theme

Tags: sublimetext3, material-design

I have something very strange just happen with Sublime Text. I'm using Material theme and yesterday the sidebar was using the theme but today it's the default theme. I don't think I did anything different, just loaded it up.

It's picking up the color scheme.

User Preferences

```
{
    "always_show_minimap_viewport": true,
    "theme": "Material-Theme.sublime-theme",
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Material Theme/schemes/Material-Theme.tmTheme",
    "font_face": "Fira Code",
    "font_options":
    [
        "gray_antialias"
    ],
    "font_size": 15,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Markdown",
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "line_padding_bottom": 3,
    "line_padding_top": 3,
    "material_theme_accent_lime": true,
    "material_theme_disable_fileicons": true,
    "material_theme_disable_tree_indicator": true,
    "material_theme_panel_separator": true,
    "material_theme_small_statusbar": true,
    "material_theme_tabs_separator": true,
    "overlay_scroll_bars": "enabled",
    "show_panel_on_build": false,
    "theme": "Default.sublime-theme",
    "use_simple_full_screen": true,
    "word_wrap": "true"
}
```

Why would this happen? Any ideas how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I was just having this issue and found the fix on the theme's official github repo section "Activate the theme".

i pasted to : **preferences > settings-User**

these lines :

```
{
"theme": "Material-Theme.sublime-theme",
"color_scheme": "Packages/Material Theme/schemes/Material-Theme.tmTheme"
}
```

after deleting these :

```
{
"color_scheme": "Packages/Material Theme/schemes/Material-Theme-Darker-OceanicNext.tmTheme",
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ]
}
```

i have sublime text 3 !!!

Comment: You may follow the instructions on the page in order to get the best experience.